# How to pass variables to spark.sql query in pyspark?

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

How to pass variables to spark.sql query in pyspark? When I query a table it fails with a `AnalysisException`. Why?

```
>>> spark.sql("select * from student").show()

+-------+--------+
|roll_no|    name|
+-------+--------+
|      1|ravindra|
+-------+--------+

>>> spark.sql("select * from student where roll_no={0} and name={1}".format(id,name)).show()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/spark-2.3.0-bin-hadoop2.6/python/pyspark/sql/session.py", line 767, in sql
    return DataFrame(self._jsparkSession.sql(sqlQuery), self._wrapped)
  File "/usr/local/spark-2.3.0-bin-hadoop2.6/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1257, in __call__
  File "/usr/local/spark-2.3.0-bin-hadoop2.6/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 69, in deco
    raise AnalysisException(s.split(': ', 1)[1], stackTrace)
pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: u"cannot resolve '`ravindra`' given input columns: [default.student.id, default.student.roll_no, default.student.name]; line 1 pos 47;\n'Project [*]\n+- 'Filter ((roll_no#21 = 0) && (name#22 = 'ravindra))\n   +- SubqueryAlias `default`.`student`\n      +- HiveTableRelation `default`.`student`, org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe, [id#20, roll_no#21, name#22]\n"
```

Comment: What was the value of `name`? How did you set the value?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I generally use the `%s` string formatter inside sql strings

```
sqlc.sql('select * from students where roll_no=%s and name="%s"' % ('1', 'ravindra')).show()
```

Looking at your sql traceback, you must have missed the quotes for the `name=` value when `ravindra` is passed to the sql string, and sql engine thinks it as a variable call.

Your sql query then becomes

```
select * from students where roll_no=1 and name=ravindra  -- no quotes
```

You can adjust your sql string to

```
spark.sql("select * from student where roll_no={0} and name='{1}'".format(id,name)).show()
```

quote your `{1}` to get your desired result.

Comment: FYI/REM - `%s` is now deprecated, and one should use the more powerful `str.format` as in the OP's post.

Comment: This results in SQL injection vulnerabilities.

Comment: @jpmc26 That's how the OP wants. Check the statement in the question. I helped with same. What's vulnerable or not is completely off-topic.

Comment: Security risks are *never* off topic. They are a concern for literally every piece of code in existence.

Comment: The dangers that the asker *doesn't* know to ask about are the ones that need pointing out the most. Do you want this person's server to leak private data or get taken over by an attacker? If not, this should be a concern to you.

Comment: Thanks. Its working. Below is the code 
Cylinders = "4"
Horsepower = "115"
df.createOrReplaceTempView("data_table")
query2 ="SELECT * FROM data_table where Cylinders= '{}' and Horsepower= '{}'".format(Cylinders,Horsepower)
dfnew =spark.sql(query2)